# Rails Paperclip - Cannot upload image correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, controller, paperclip

I am making a small rails application that requires being able to upload an image to a post/ad and then displaying that image.

I am using the **'Paperclip'** gem to handle the image uploads.
Whenever I create my post/ad the default 'missing.jpg' is displayed, not my image.

**Ads Controller**

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ad, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /ads
  # GET /ads.json
  def index
    @ads = Ad.all
  end

  # GET /ads/1
  # GET /ads/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /ads/new
  def new
    @ad = Ad.new
  end

  # GET /ads/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /ads
  # POST /ads.json
  def create
    @ad = Ad.new(ad_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ad.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ad, notice: 'Ad was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @ad }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @ad.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /ads/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ads/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ad.update(ad_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ad, notice: 'Ad was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @ad.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /ads/1
  # DELETE /ads/1.json
  def destroy
    @ad.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ads_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ad
      @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ad_params
      params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :url, images_attributes: [:preview])
    end
end
```

**Ad _form View**

```
<style type="text/css">
.header {
  display: none!important;
}
</style>

<%= form_for @ad, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <% if @ad.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@ad.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ad from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @ad.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <span>Contact (URL, Mobile, Address)</span><br>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :preview %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Ad Model**

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :title, :url, :preview
    belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :preview, :default_url => "missing.jpg"

  validates :title, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :url, length: { maximum: 20 }
end
```

**Ad Index View**

```
<h1>Listing ads</h1>




    <% @ads.each do |ad| %>
    <div class="adspace_grid">
      <%= image_tag ad.preview.url %>
      <div class="text_info">
      <span class="bold"><%= ad.title %></span> / 
      <span class="bold">Contact : </span><%= ad.url %>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <%= link_to 'Delete', ad, :method => :delete %> 
    <% end %>


<br>

<%= link_to 'New Ad', new_ad_path %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT :
This is the error in the Google Chrome Console.
[image: Error Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you are permitting `ad` attributes:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def ad_params
  params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :url, images_attributes: [:preview])
end
```

I'm not sure why you have `images_attributes: [:preview]` here.  The method definition should just be:

```
def ad_params
  params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :url, :preview)
end
```

The reason you are not getting the uploaded picture and are getting the default `missing.jpg` is because the your image file selected in the form did not get created because you were not permitting `:preview` in your `ad_params` method.

**Update:**

As far as the path is concerned, you should be able to supply other parameters uch as `url` and `path` to `has_attached_file`.  Something like following:

```
# app/models/ad.rb

has_attached_file :preview, :default_url => "missing.jpg", 
                  :url  => "/assets/ads/preview/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/preview/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

With this all your uploaded preview files will be in `public/assets/ads/preview/:id/:style/` directory.

Comment: Thanks! That parameter definitely was a problem but now whenever I make an ad, no image is displayed but when I check if the image exists, through Google Developer Console I can navigate to the image. So it is definitely there but for some reason is not being displayed.

Comment: Try setting a size for your image.  Have a look here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Hmm, I've just done that but it doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: Did you verify the uploaded image and it's path?  Can you open that image from your OS file browser?  Also check the generated URL is is correct by inspecting the image's src attribute.

Comment: Yes, I have verified the path and it links up to the file that I am trying to make visible, in my rails code, I have the views set up but when I view the html code the <img> does not appear.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just checked again and my image source is linking to '/system/ads/previews/000/000/053/medium/Capture7.JPG?1386782563' but that then would be trying to take me to 'ads/system/ads/previews/000/000/053/medium/Capture7.JPG?1386782563'. Is there anyway possible that I would be able to add '../' in front of that URL via rails?

Comment: I have also edited my question with the error code that Chrome Console is giving me.

Comment: @coreypizzle, please see the update and give that a try.

Comment: Okay, I've tried that and It must have been linking to the correct location as whenever I try to change the url path it gives me a 404 not found in the console so I am really not sure what this could be.

Comment: Whoops, I'm so stupid the only reason that it wouldn't display was because my model name has 'Ad' in it therefore making Adblocker render it invisible.